# What a grating on GAIA RVS spectroscope?

Tags: gaia

What size of the grating on GAIA RVS spectroscope ?

### How many lines on mm, or what defraction angle for 850 nm wavelenth light ?

I find some more details here: http://sci.esa.int/gaia/44092-gaia-rvs-grating/ and http://sci.esa.int/gaia/44093-state-of-the-art-grating-for-gaia/
The GAIA RVS grating has dimensions of 20.5 cm × 15.5 cm and 302.11 grooves per mm.

Comment: For RVS, Gaia uses two prisms, a blue and red one. That's a good thing to google.

Comment: You are wrong. Prisms uses in the photometric instrument - spectrometer of low resolution. RVS (radial velocity spectrometer) use the grating, see http://sci.esa.int/gaia/40129-payload-module/?fbodylongid=1916

Comment: Also see the question on this sight - Why does Gaia use only calcium NIR lines for stellar radial velocity measurements? - https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/why-does-gaia-use-only-calcium-nir-lines-for-stellar-radial-velocity-measurement

Comment: Ah you're right, I confused those two parts. The calcium triplet is simply very well detectable in most stars, just as the document you've linked also states.